# Remove webkit browser scrollbar's top margin css

Tags: css, scrollbar

**CODE:**

```
<style>
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 23px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background-color: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: silver;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
      background-color: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
      background-color: transparent;
}
</style>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2zcxnL66/

On that code in chrome, other things about scrollbar is good and nicely working.

But I care some margin of scrollbar. 
It looks like there are some margin for top corner or bottom corner of scrollbar track.

**Question:**
How can I remove these margin? I want to make scrollbar goes top fully as if margin-top_or_bottom-of-scrollbar-track:0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't margin but the spaces taken by the arrows you made transparent. So instead you can make them `display:none` :

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 23px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background-color: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: silver;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
      background-color: transparent;
      display:none; /*added this */
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
      background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p style="padding-top:0; margin-top:0; text-align:right">
Here is problem --------------------------------->
</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<p style="padding-top:0; margin-top:0; text-align:right">
Here is problem --------------------------------->
</p>
</body>
```